# How can Vue.js to create a meta tag to store the `csrftoken` like Django, Laravel?

Tags: vue.js

How can the Vue.js template create a meta tag like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-xsrf-token):

> in addition to checking for the CSRF token as a POST parameter, the VerifyCsrfToken middleware will also check for the X-CSRF-TOKEN request header. You could, for example, store the token in a HTML meta tag:
>   `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

But the `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` is use the server language, how can Vue.js to create a meta tag to store the `csrftoken`?

---

**EDIT-1**

My project is Django-Rest-Framework as the backend, and Vue.js as the frontend.
they are separation of frontend and backend (Apis).

Answer (score 0):

You can try what [this](https://medium.com/@m_ramsden/passing-data-from-laravel-to-vue-98b9d2a4bd23) blog said. He exposed a props from vue template.

```
//Add this to your vue js
<script>
export default {
    props: ['csrfToken'],
    mounted () {
        // Do something useful with the data in the template
        console.dir(this.csrfToken)
    }
}
</script>

<!-- Add this to your html/php/template -->
<sample-component :csrf-token="'{!! csrf_token() !!}'">
</sample-component>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry i was out the weekend, i'm not familiar with the django-rest-framework so i can't really help anymore. But i tried and read some of there documentation regarding this. here are the two documents i've found online;[this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#s-acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-is-true) and [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/)

The first link states that:

If you activate CSRF_USE_SESSIONS, you must include the CSRF token in your HTML and read the token from the DOM with JavaScript:

```
{% csrf_token %}
<script type="text/javascript">
// using jQuery
var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
</script>
```

So i think you need to activate "CSRF_USE_SESSIONS" first before you can use the codeblock above.

Comment: My backend is Django-Rest-Framework provides REST APIs.

Comment: ahh ok, should have added that the first time. but still same principle applies, do you know how to generate the token from django?

Comment: You can check this link that i've found, maybe this can help:
[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-ajax)

Comment: I use the debugger, in there , I console the `document.cookie`, there is no `csrftoken` and `sessionid`, when I request a api, they will appear in the Cookie in the request header.

Comment: How do you make the request? did you use an ajax? or when it is requested on page itself?

Comment: I use the Axios, it is based on xhr.